flutter go_router with riverpod redirect exception / Location cannot be empty. / redirect is not being notified
I'm developing my application using riverpod as state management and I've used go_router package for routing management specially for redirecting user to login page of refreshToken renewal failed.
so what i want is that i want to watch my refreshTokenViewModel inside the redirect method so that if the refreshTokenState is failure i want to redirect the user to the login page.
the problem is that the redirect method is not being notified. I've knew that accidently when i tried to access the page one more time (the state is now updated) I'm being redirected to the login page.
please refer to this video : video link
so first time when trying to access any page when I'm not authorized I'm getting :
======== Exception caught by foundation library ====================================================
The following GoException was thrown while dispatching notifications for GoRouteInformationProvider:
Location cannot be empty.

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      canonicalUri (package:go_router/src/path_utils.dart:125:5)
#1      RouteConfiguration.findMatch (package:go_router/src/configuration.dart:296:31)
#2      _RouteMatchListDecoder.convert (package:go_router/src/match.dart:947:23)
#3      Codec.decode (dart:convert/codec.dart:30:34)
#4      GoRouteInformationParser.parseRouteInformationWithDependencies (package:go_router/src/parser.dart:71:32)
#5      _RouterState._processRouteInformation (package:flutter/src/widgets/router.dart:749:8)
#6      _RouterState._handleRouteInformationProviderNotification (package:flutter/src/widgets/router.dart:767:5)
#7      ChangeNotifier.notifyListeners (package:flutter/src/foundation/change_notifier.dart:433:24)


but when trying to access it again im being redirected.
I've search on the internet all day long for this type of exception but i found nothing.
what i have tried :
router provider :
final _key = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();

final routerProvider = Provider<GoRouter>((ref) {

***//when using watch the app remain stuck on the splash page*  **
   //final authState = ref.read(refreshTokenViewModelProvider);

final authStateNotifier = ValueNotifier(RefreshTokenState.initial);
  ref
    ..onDispose(authStateNotifier.dispose)
    ..listen(refreshTokenViewModelProvider, (_, value) {
      logger.w("listener value state ${value.refreshTokenState}");
      logger.d("listener authStateNotifier value ${authStateNotifier.value}");
      authStateNotifier.value = value.refreshTokenState;
      logger.d("listener auth value after modification ${authStateNotifier.value}");
    });

  return GoRouter(
    navigatorKey: _key,
    debugLogDiagnostics: true,
    initialLocation: '/',
   // refreshListenable: authState, ***//with/without it nothing changed***
    refreshListenable: authStateNotifier,
    routes: [....],
    errorBuilder: (context, state) =>
        const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
    redirect: (context, state) {
//cannot watch provider here Cannot use ref functions after the dependency of a //provider changed but before the provider rebuilt
    //  bool isRefreshTokenFailure = (authState.refreshTokenState == RefreshTokenState.failure);

      bool isRefreshTokenFailure = (authStateNotifier.value == RefreshTokenState.failure);
      logger.f("is ref token failure ? ........ ${isRefreshTokenFailure}");
      if (isRefreshTokenFailure) {
        return "/login";
      } else {
        return null;
      }
    },
  );
});


Logs when trying to access the page for the first time :
I/flutter (14770): │ ! listener value state RefreshTokenState.failure
I/flutter (14770): │  listener authStateNotifier value RefreshTokenState.initial
I/flutter (14770): │  listener auth value after modification RefreshTokenState.failure

======== Exception caught by foundation library ====================================================
The following GoException was thrown while dispatching notifications for GoRouteInformationProvider:
Location cannot be empty.


Logs on second time :
I/flutter (14770): │  is ref token failure ? ........ true
I/flutter (14770): │  is ref token failure ? ........ true

main widget build method
didnt know what to use both didnt work .
 routeInformationParser: router.routeInformationParser,
 routeInformationProvider: router.routeInformationProvider,
 routerDelegate: router.routerDelegate,

or :
routerConfig: ref.watch(routerProvider),

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext outContext) {
      ref.watch(themeRProvider);
      return MaterialApp.router(
        routerConfig: ref.watch(routerProvider),
        // routeInformationParser: router.routeInformationParser,
        // routeInformationProvider: router.routeInformationProvider,
        // routerDelegate: router.routerDelegate,
        themeMode: themeProvider.themeMode == ThemeModeOption.light
            ? ThemeMode.light
            : themeProvider.themeMode == ThemeModeOption.dark
                ? ThemeMode.dark
                : ThemeMode.system,
        theme: lightTheme,
        darkTheme: darkTheme,
        // home: SplashPage(),
      );
  }

snippet of refreshTokenViewModelProvider :
enum RefreshTokenState { initial, loading, success, failure , networkFailure}
class RefreshTokenViewModel extends ChangeNotifier {
  RefreshTokenState _refreshTokenViewModelState = RefreshTokenState.initial;
  RefreshTokenState get refreshTokenState => _refreshTokenViewModelState;

  setFailure(UserError error) {
    _refreshTokenViewModelState = RefreshTokenState.failure;
    notifyListeners();
  }

Future<void> refreshToken() async {
    var response = await refreshTokenRepository.refreshToken();
    if (response is Failure) {
      setFailure(UserError(response.errorMessage));
    } else {
      setSuccess();
    }
  }

}


You need to create a local ValueNotifier that will be passed as a refreshListenable to the router. Use ref.listen to listen to refreshTokenViewModelProvider and update the ValueNotifier with it.
final routerProvider = Provider<GoRouter>((ref) {
  final authStateNotifier = ValueNotifier(RefreshTokenState.initial);
  ref
    ..onDispose(authStateNotifier.dispose)
    ..listen(refreshTokenViewModelProvider, (_, value) {
      authStateNotifier.value = value;
    });

  // ...

  return GoRouter(
    // ...
    refreshListenable: authStateNotifier,
    redirect: (_, state) {
      final authState = ref.read(refreshTokenViewModelProvider);
      // ...
    },

See full example here.

Hello , thank you for your answer,
I've updated my authStateNotifier , but the problem still persist
when trying to access the page when unauthorized I'm still getting Location cannot be empty. exception
but when trying to access it again I'm being redirecting properly(but the new route is being pushed not pushed as replacement by this the user can press backbutton :(

im gonna update my post please if you can help i will be very happy.

There's no notifier that needs to be updated, because authStateNotifier, as I demonstrated in the code above, is a totally new notifier, and it's local to the provider body. If you follow my example code correctly, it should be working fine.

@MRS Sure, that would be great

i cannot find anything related to Location cannot be empty. exception since Monday and I'm stuck with this :D

That exception happens when you give an empty string for the route path.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
